# How to download attachments using c#

Tags: salesforce

I want to download the attachments from my cases to the local folder using c# code. For ex: This is my attachment

https://simpleaudio.desk.com/api/v2/cases/8/attachments/8897101/url
How can I download this to local folder

I have tried using web client but it is throwing me an error. Can anyone help me to achieve this

Comment: what sort of error are we talking about?

Comment: Is this url can be downloaded using webclient @Daniel

Comment: are you trying to grab the content of the url using c# ?

Comment: The url consists of an image and I wan to download it using c#